# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the router section, we want to route the pages through Nested Routes, but there is a problem, it does not recognize the pages ...
Codes:

```
{
            path: '/',
            component: require('../view/layout/Layout').default,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: require('../view/Home').default,
                    name: 'home'
                },
                {
                    path: 'post/:slug',
                    component: require('../view/Post/PostShow').default,
                    name: 'post-show'
                },
            ]
        },
```

Errors:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/Navigationdrawer' in '/home/../Desktop/../resources/js/view/layout'
 @ ./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 11:0-62 16:22-38
 @ ./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/js/view/layout/Layout.vue
 @ ./resources/js/router/router.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Comment: Ether 'Navigationdrawer' doesn't exist or it's not where  `/home/../Desktop/../resources/js/view/layout` thinks it is. Make sure the import in `view/layout` is correct.

Comment: @ ray hatfield  ...imposted in the Layout.vue file ... import Navigationdrawer from "../components/Navigationdrawer";

Comment: And is that the correct relative path? Is that the correct filename? Same casing, same extension?

Comment: @rayhatfield The file exists and is in the same folder and its path is correct ...

Comment: Add your directory hierarchy and the contents of `view/layout/Layout`

Comment: @rayhatfield ...Well, this is the path that you said the file exists and is defined ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

```
import Navigationdrawer from "../../components/Navigationdrawer";
```